# Assembly AVR Instruction LDI r22, 0x3D

Tags: assembly, binary, avr, instructions

Hi guys I'm trying to work out an AVR Instruction to machine code

```
LDI r22, 0x3D

LDI Rd, K 

1110 KKKK dddd KKKK
```

so far I've got

```
1110 0011 dddd 1101
```

, how can `dddd` be covered in 4 bits if the maximum is 15.. ?

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: thank you Joachim Isaksson, to confirm it encoding 22 value would be 0110

Comment: and LDI r22, 0x3D to binary is 1110001101101101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> LDI - Load Immediate
>
> Description:
> Loads an 8 bit constant directly to register 16 to 31.

To encode a value of 16-31, you only need 4 bits (3-0) if you assume bit 4 to always be 1.

In your case, the encoding would be;

```
1110 0011 0110 1101 (where dddd is 6 since 16 + 6 = 22)
```